# Can you identify what's corrupting my signal? I see a lot of "empty spaces" between datapoints

Tags: matlab, analog-to-digital

I'm trying to acquire a signal from the brain of a laboratory animal under anesthesia via the implantation of silicon probes. I've done this many times, but upon testing some new recording hardware I stumbled upon a peculiar situation after loading the data in MATLAB:
[image: Sample of the signal]

Zoomed in:
[image: Zoom in]

It looks like some data points are missing, while they actually cluster above and below certain values. Data was acquired at 30 KHz and bandpassed between 0.1 and 8000 Hz.

I've never seen something like that before, and it puzzled my colleagues too. Do you have an idea of what could be corrupting the signal or how would a pattern like that appear?

Comment: My first assumption is that this might be an artifact of your acquisition method. Can you tell us more about what happens from brain  to plot?

Comment: Do you have a way to independently test the functioning of the equipment?  Have you changed anything in your lab setup (new anything, someone dropped the most expensive part, etc.)?

Comment: Yes sure, I think it might be worth noting that if I connect the exact same silicon probes with another acquisition system of another manufacturer, I don't see this artifact. So the issue lies with the digitization/filtering operated by this new hardware. I don't know if it's useful, but the hardware that gives this problem operates with "digital headstages", meaning that the signal is digitized close to the brain then sent to an FPGA board, whereas the hardware which does not show any issue uses "analog headstages" and the signal is digitized in the main unit.

Comment: Standard debug process: feed it a sine wave or "known" signal. That would show clearly what the problem is.

Comment: This is all brand new equipment, except for the probes themselves. We asked a nearby lab to set up the system again in their room as if it were their own stuff and try to record an hour just to test, telling them we had a problem but without disclosing the specifics. We found the same situation in their files.

Comment: That's a great point Hilmar, thank you. You reminded me that I actually fed it a sine wave when I was setting it all up, and I don't recall it having this problem but I will try again for sure. The only issue I see is that the sine wave from the Minirator follows a different path than the biological one; the former goes Minirator->BNC->FPGA board, whereas the latter: brain->silicon probe->probe adaptor->digital headstage-> SPI cable -> FPGA board. I'm not aware of a way to feed a sine wave straight to the digital headstage, but this will help me understand if it's the headstage or the FPGA.

Comment: I am not sure this is applicable here because I don't know what exactly you are measuring, but I've seen similar artefacts from time-of-flight measurements. There the available temporal resolution was limited by the reaction speed of the microcontroller that did the data acquisition and it changed with the state of the microcontroller. Depending on whether it was servicing an interrupt or busy with something else, the event-time would incorrectrly be attributed to either a point before or after the functional black-out occured.

Comment: So if you are measuring anything that is related to time, typically on the scale of nanoseconds to microseconds, this could be a possible explanation.

Comment: @F.V.: debug it one step at a time. Start with a sine wave into the FPGA. If that checks out, you want to insert a known signal as early in the signal chain as possible. I assume that the output of the probe adaptor is an analog signal, so you should be able to insert there if you get the voltage level and impedance right. The info you need should be in the data sheet of the headstage amp and/or the probe adapter.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you for the suggestions! Tomorrow I'll try what you suggested and I'll get back to you.

Comment: This looks like an issue with the digitizer, it doesn’t produce 0, or values are somehow rounded away from zero. The band-pass filtering you applied would move the zero point around in an attempt to remove the lowest frequencies, which is why the empty band shifts up and down. You should definitely examine the data without filtering.